# What is this Bean Sprout looking plant?

Tags: identification, beans

I have a section of my garden that has been covered by a wooden board. The area underneath this wooden board was very damp and dark. There was this strange plant underneath the wooden board and I was wondering if anyone could identify it (click to enlarge):

[image: Bean Sprout?]

To me, this looks like a [bean sprout](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&biw=1440&bih=752&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=bean%20sprout&oq=bean%20sprout&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l4.10079.10079.0.254798.1.1.0.0.0.0.271.271.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.271....0.-BHdCf7qfU4). But I don't know where it would have come from. I am in Canberra, Australia and the other plants in the garden are parsley, lettuce, broad beans, blueberries and spring onion.

Comment: If you doesn't mean about killing it, just remove it. On the bottom (really on the middle), probably you will find the remaining of the seed, which help identification.  Or just like Bamboo wrote, wait. I'm thinking about some tree (from seeds in the wood).

Comment: I think I know what it is now, there is this tree that has been dropping seeds all over my garden. This looks similar from the leaves, but I assumed it was a different plant because of the colour. Now that I know the colour is just from germinating under low light, it must be the same seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever this is will reveal itself shortly - any seed which germinates, or any growth which begins underneath something which blocks light will look not dissimilar, i.e., yellow 'leaves' and white stem. Those yellow 'leaves' might be cotyledons, and if they are, it's usually impossible to tell from those what the plant might be - it's the second pair of leaves (which will be the true leaves) that are more definitive. Now that it's exposed to light, it should also turn green, so if you still don't know what it is as it begins to grow properly, please post another photograph.